# Using renderscript for processing and mediacodec for encoding

Tags: android, renderscript, android-mediacodec

I am trying to develop a camera app that does some video processing before recording the video. I have decided to use Rendrscript for the processing since it provides many of the operations that I want to use. And I want to use MediaCodec for encoding. I have found a few samples(including [Grafika](https://github.com/google/grafika)) that shows how to use GLES for processing but I haven't found a sample that shows how to do it with RenderScript. Trying to replace GLES with Renderscript I have the following questions:

1. I create RenderScript output ***Allocation*** from Encoder input surface. In the Grafika sample EGL ***swapbuffer()*** is used to send buffer to encoder. Does ***Allocation.ioSend()*** do the same thing?
2. In EGL ***setPresentationTime()*** is used to set the time-stamp. How do I set the time-stamp in Renderscript's ***Allocation***?
3. Should I be using ***MediaCodec.queueInputBuffer()*** instead to submit input buffer and time-stamp? In that case should I still call ***Allocation.ioSend()*** before calling queueInputBuffer?

Answer (score 1):

I came across this same issue and the solution I use is to set the timestamp via EGL, similar to [RecordFBOActivity#doFrame](https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/a5ae09c/src/com/android/grafika/RecordFBOActivity.java#L974). In order to do this an intermediate Allocation is used to bridge the gap between RenderScript and OpenGL/EGL.

Let's view the data flow as a processing pipeline with stages.

**Original Pipeline**

```
[Camera]
   --> [ImageAllocation]
       --> [RenderScript]
           --> [MediaCodecSurfaceAllocationForEncoder]
               --> [MediaCodec]
```

In original pipeline all buffers are RS allocations.

`MediaCodecSurfaceAllocation` is based on the Surface returned from encoder, i.e., `MediaCodec#getSurface()`.

**New Pipeline**

```
[Camera]
    --> [ImageAllocation]
        --> [RenderScript]
            --> [IntermediateAllocation]
                --> [EglWindowSurfaceForEncoder]
                    --> [MediaCodec]
```

In new pipeline there are two big changes, `IntermediateAllocation` and `EglWindowSurfaceForEncoder`

`IntermediateAllocation` is a SurfaceTexture-based Allocation, similar to the ful screen texture blitter used in [CameraCaptureActivity](https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/a5ae09c522b2e905f93c85adb1f25c5a3f407a9d/src/com/android/grafika/CameraCaptureActivity.java#L612).

`EglWindowSurfaceForEncoder` wraps the encoder's input surface, similar to [RecordFBOActivity#startEncoder](https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/a5ae09c/src/com/android/grafika/RecordFBOActivity.java#L815)

The key here is to set your own [OnFrameAvailableListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/SurfaceTexture.OnFrameAvailableListener.html).

**Setup Code**

```
void setup() {
    mEglWindowSurfaceForEncoder= new WindowSurface(mEglCore, encoderCore.getInputSurface(), true);

    mFullScreen = new FullFrameRect(
            new Texture2dProgram(Texture2dProgram.ProgramType.TEXTURE_EXT));
    mTextureId = mFullScreen.createTextureObject();
    mSurfaceTexture = new SurfaceTexture(mTextureId);    

    Type renderType = new Type.Builder(renderScript, Element.RGBA_8888(renderScript))
        .setX(width)
        .setY(height)
        .create();

    mIntermediateAllocation = Allocation.createTyped(
        renderScript,
        renderType,
                                                               Allocation.USAGE_SCRIPT | Allocation.USAGE_IO_OUTPUT);

    mIntermediateAllocation .setSurface(surface);

    mAllocationFromCamera = ...
}
```

**OnNewCameraImage**

```
mIntermediateAllocation.copyFrom(mAllocationFromCamera);
```

**OnFrameAvailableListener**

```
mSurfaceTexture.setOnFrameAvailableListener(
    new SurfaceTexture.OnFrameAvailableListener() {
        public void onFrameAvailableListener(SurfaceTexture) {

             //latch the image data from camera
             mSurfaceTexture.updateTexImage();

             // Draw the frame.
             mSurfaceTexture.getTransformMatrix(mSTMatrix);
             mFullScreen.drawFrame(mTextureId, mSTMatrix);

             // latch frame to encoder input
             mEglWindowSurfaceForEncoder.setPresentationTimes(timestampNanos);
             mEglWindowSurfaceForEncoder.swapBuffers();

        }        
    }
}
```

The above code must run in EGL context (ie on the OpenGl rendering thread).